# Increase the height of Filter List AG Grid Set Filter

Tags: angular9, ag-grid-angular

Currently I am using Ag Grid v27.3.0, and contents inside  filter list in Set Filter not being displayed correctly as shown in the below image. Data is not getting wrapped correctly.
Below is what i have tried, but of no use.

Am i missing anything here?

```
   :host ::ng-deep .ag-set-filter-item 
{
    height: max-content;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be dynamic but you can set the height with the following [config](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-set/#reference-ISetFilterParams-cellHeight).

```
    { field: 'athlete', filter: true, filterParams: {
      cellHeight: 35
    } },
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/OOIbFw17EMxJWY72?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts